# Users who once joined Beta Testing are not able to Rate and submit Reviews for my Android App on the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

**The Problem**

Users once joined Beta Testing is not able to Rate and submit Reviews for my Android App on the Play Store. And now, new users can see a Rating Bar and Submit a Review option. But Users once joined Beta Testing can see it.

**What I have Tried**

- I added *Contact Details* in Google Play Console Settings
- I paused the Beta Track
- I have published a Beta release without any apk/app bundle
- I have uninstalled and installed the app, cleared cache of Play Store App...

**The Expected Behaviour**

All Users are able to Rate and submit Reviews for my Android App on the Play Store.

**More Info**

- The app has been published in Beta on 27 Aug
- The app has been published in Production Track on 15 Sep
- [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=phone.vishnu.quotes) is the Link to the App - (This is not for promotion. Please don't mark this question as spam!)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

**Edit** : Screenshots

[image: ¹]
[image: ²]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 5 Reviews right now. So I don't think user are not able to rate and review.

If a user is not able to rate and review than only 2 possibilities for any application:

1. User has not installed application. In this case, if the user has not installed the application they are not able to submit rating and review.
2. User has joined Beta program(or any other internal app sharing etc.). If the user is joined in Beta program than they are only allowed to give private feedback to developer, check this Image.
   [image: Image 1]

It is really strange why it is not showing rating options.

But I found something fishy:

1. In screenshot last update is showing Sep,12 2020
2. You said Your last update was 15 Sep.
3. Play store last update is September 22, 2020

If your last update in Production is after 15 Sep than it must be same in device screenshot.

- This is because of either Playstore issue or cache issue.
- If you leave from beta than Playstore takes some time make it normal.
- If the device is not able to see the latest version maybe you have some changes where device is not compatible (but still rating should be visible)

Apart from these, I found 1 other thing when you have multiple email login and you have joined with Beta from abc@gmail.com and you are checking inside xyz@gmail.com than it will not allow giving ratings. You must check you have selected same email account while you want to rate. [image: Image 2]
As you can see I have used different account and I am not able to give a rating or review. I must use the same account while I'm in the Beta version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have noticed that reviews now. I updated my question - [Users Once Joined Beta can't review/rate]. Users who once joined Beta Testing can't submit reviews now. (Even though now they are using the production release). Any idea why these users can't review/rate? Thank you once again for your support...

Comment: Added screenshots. Both are from different SmartPhones. Please take a look...

Comment: Thank you for your help... I'll try. Sorry for being late. I came across your edit now...